# Verb to refer to putting debris aside with machinery

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

> The screen was showing a close up of some buildings in ruins.
>   Excavators and bulldozers **[...]** debris aside, while the survivors watched
>   the work with anguish and despair on their faces.

OK, I guess I could use **put**. But I think it sounds too soft for such heavy work. I also thought of **push** but I guess excavators don't actually push things? (unless **push** can also be used for 'grabbing things and putting them aside').

So I can't think of the proper verb. Any suggestions?

Comment: Moved? (And actually, bulldozers **do** push)

Comment: @Andrew Leach I know. I was talking about the excavators. Moved is good choice. Thanks!

Comment: The technical name for the operation is '(site) clearance' -- beyond that it's up to the author and the contextual mood to determine an appropriate word to be used.

Comment: What Kris said, so in your case, you can say the bulldozers were clearing debris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Clear*?

- based on what they're trying to achieve

*Shift*?

- includes lifting (diggers) and pushing (bulldozers)

Answer (score 1):

How does thrust sound?

Machines can be used to thrust debris aside.

Answer (score 1):

Clear/move/remove (without aside)

Answer (score 1):

I must really be at my wits end for writing this.  It would depend upon what you wish to infer.  Put implies commonness, disinterest, a sense that the do-er (in this case the bulldozer drivers) have not a clue or a care about the effects of their actions.

Shove implies a more aggressive intent, almost a punishment, ill will among the do-ers.  A poet here answering this.

One might imply indifference;  one might imply malice.  Your call.

Comment: B.D. Love Please let us rely upon you providing references to authoritative sources and please read this:  https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Shove? To shove is to push.

> Excavators shoved debris aside, while the survivors watched the work with anguish and despair on their face.